# Can I find supremum of $(ax^2+bx+c)/x^2$ for non-zero $a, b, c$? Is there any condition for the function to converge?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Actually I think I am wrong. 
I am trying to find,

$$\sup \limits_x \frac{{a{x^2} + bx + c}}{{{x^2}}}$$

I know that the above function is undefined at $x\to0$. I know I cannot use L'hospital rule here. Is there any condition that will make the objective function converge at $x \to 0$?

Comment: For that the limit $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ax^2+bx+c}{x^2}$ will have to exist and be non-zero. Can $b$ or $c$ be non-zero? The function is equivalent to $a + \frac bx + \frac c{x^2}$ for $x \neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you. a, b, c is non-zero.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I don't agree your argument of the finiteness. For instance, take $1+1/x-1/x^2$, then its supremum is $5/4$.

Comment: @Tab1e You are right. I think then $b,c$ can be possibly negative. I was too focused on the convergence at $x \to 0$, that I forgot only supremum existence was required. Of course, the infimum of this function is negative infinite (the limit at zero is negative infinite i.e. convergence does not happen there), but then that means that you can neglect the part near $0$ if you are searching for a supremum.